# Symfony2 Composer install calls wrong php installation/version internally

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to set up Symfony 2.5 via Composer.
First I am calling:

```
 php5.3.8-cli /kunden/81425/composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition hhcadm/ "2.5.*"
```

This works until at some point it is internally not calling **php5.3.8-cli** anymore but somehow uses **php**. The problem is that **php** is version **4.4.9** and this causes following effect:

```
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in <b>/kunden/81425/hhcadm/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.
```

The error makes sense as 4.4.9 is too old. How can I tell Composer/Symfony installer which php installation to use during the install routine?

Same happens for me when I call:

```
php5.3.8-cli /kunden/81425/composer.phar install
```

I am pretty shure there must be a config / param for that but I can't find it for hours now.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your OS ? If you are on Linux, what is the result of 'type php' ?

Comment: @griotteau: Linux 2.6.32.53-grsec-x86_64 x86_64

Gentoo Base System release 2.0.3

php is /usr/local/bin/php

Comment: @griotteau: and php -v shows me
`PHP 4.4.9 (cgi) (built: May  9 2012 09:57:22)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Optimizer v3.3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2007, by Zend Technologies
`

which is exactly what I expect - the command php should be the old one while the new one is at least php53 for cgi and see above for CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'php' must be the PHP5 executable.
The only solution i see is to modify the PATH, launch the composer command (and eventually restore the old path)

For example :

```
OLDPATH=$PATH
PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
php /kunden/81425/composer.phar install
PATH=$OLDPATH
```

To help you, you can also create a small script 'composer.sh' :

```
#!/bin/sh
OLDPATH=$PATH
PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
php /kunden/81425/composer.phar $*
PATH=$OLDPATH
```

And you call 'composer.sh install'

Edit : if all php binaries are in the same, you can create symbolic links

For example :

```
mkdir /usr/local/bin/php5
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php53-cli /usr/local/bin/php5/php
```

And so PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/php5:$PATH

Edit: If you are not allowed to create /usr/local/bin/php5 then just use any other folder like:

```
#!/bin/sh
OLDPATH=$PATH
PATH=/kunden/81425/php5:$PATH
php /kunden/81425/composer.phar $*
PATH=$OLDPATH
```

Comment: Is there any way to override the path locally only within certain directories? The reason is that this is a shared hosting where it has to be set up - so I can use many different PHP versions but can not change fundamental settings that would affect other users.

Comment: change are only for the session ; and if you use a composer.sh script, it's only for the user that use this script !

Comment: that sounds great. Am I just overseeing smth?
In my case *php* is not in its own bin directory. All versions are in the same directoy: /usr/local/bin/*. For example like: /usr/local/bin/php5-55STABLE-STANDARD or /usr/local/bin/php.
 Is there any way to directly link the sessions *php* to */usr/local/bin/php5-55STABLE-STANDARD*?

Comment: Hum, it's a little more difficult ... I have edited my answer

Comment: perfect! I edited your answer, as the ln -s seems to have a vice versa param order and added my.